# C++ no matching function for call to erase in vector

Tags: c++, function, c++11, vector, erase

I have been researching and trying to figure out this error for hours with no success. I am unable to erase from a vector, given an index to erase. The function to erase a given index is in tuple.cpp, as outlined in tuple.h.

tuple.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Tuple {
    private:
        vector<string> tuVec;
    public:
        Tuple() {};
        string toString() const;
        void eraseFromVec(int index) const;
        bool operator< (const Tuple &right) const {
            string temp = toString();
            string temp2 = right.toString();
            return temp < temp2;
        }
};
```

tuple.cpp:

```
#include "tuple.h"

void Tuple::eraseFromVec(int index) const {
    tuVec.erase(tuVec.begin() + index);
    return;
}
```

Each Tuple object is a member of a set, which is a member of class Relation.

Relation.h:

```
#pragma once

#include "tuple.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

class Relation {
    private:
        string name;
        set<Tuple> tuples;
    public:
        Relation(string rName, Scheme rScheme);
        void addTuple(Tuple newTuple);
};
```

And here is the code that calls the erase function:

```
set<Tuple>::iterator it;
    for(it = tuples.begin(); it != tuples.end(); ++it) {
        int size = it->tuVec.size() - 1;
        int i;
        for(i = size; i > -1; --i) {
            bool isIn = false;
            int j;
            int size2 = tempRel.toKeep.size();
            for(j = 0; j < size2; ++j) {
                if(//condition) {
                    isIn = true;
                }
            }
            if(!isIn) {
                it->eraseFromVec(i);
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the error message I'm getting: (I tried typing it here but it didn't work for some reason, so I'm attaching a picture of it)

[My error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7Jcb.jpg)

I hope this hasn't been asked before. I've been searching the internet for hours trying to find a solution but I've been unable to. I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Either remove the const-qualifier from eraseFromVec(int) or declare tuVec as mutable. Otherwise eraseFromVec will access tuVec via const reference, and modifying a const vector doesnt work.

Comment: @Chemistree Declaring tuVec as mutable worked. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3):

It seems that your problem is that your function `eraseFromVec` has a `const` qualifier. But it calls the `erase` function of `std::vector` which is non const. Just remove the const qualifier and it should work fine.